# XML if unset node cant get variable value

Tags: php, xml, variables, foreach, unset

So I unset each element from XML string

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<cars>  
<car_id>26395593</car_id>
<standart>0</standart>
<model>2</model> 
</cars>
</xml>
XML;
```

//Load XML into variable;

```
$concerts = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($concerts->xpath('/*/cars/*') as $child) {
    $chil = $child;

    echo "Before= " .$chil ."\n";
    unset( $child[0] );
    echo "After= " .$chil ."\n";
}
```

Now Result is like this

```
Before= 26395593
After= 
Before= 0
After= 
Before= 2
After=
```

Why `$chil` variable is unsetting too? How to save `$child` value to variable?

Comment: It's working fine. Maybe you have different code than in question? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d928e46b2dbb29eef9f53f6e40447ba4440c40e5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML is an abstraction for the DOM. $child and $child[0] are separate SimpleXMLElement objects, but access the same DOM node. The unset() not just deletes the SimpleXMLElement object, but removes the node from the DOM, too.

So after that the second SimpleXMLElement objects refers to a removed DOM node.

With a little modification to your example, you can get an warning for it:

```
$concerts = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($concerts->xpath('/*/cars/*') as $child) {
    echo "Before= " .$child->asXml() ."\n";
    unset( $child[0] );
    echo "After= " .$child->asXml() ."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Before= <car_id>26395593</car_id>

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): Node no longer exists in /tmp/e... on line 19
After= 
Before= <standart>0</standart>

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): Node no longer exists in /tmp/e... on line 19
After= 
Before= <model>2</model>

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): Node no longer exists in /tmp/e... on line 19
After=
```

You should avoid unsetting SimpleXMLElement objects. Keep the original document the same, read values from it and create a new XML document if you need to store the data in another format.

To "disconnect" the value from the XML node, cast the SimpleXMLElement object into a scalar:

```
$concerts = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($concerts->xpath('/*/cars/*') as $child) {
    $value = (string)$child;    
    echo "Before= " .$value."\n";
    unset( $child[0] );
    echo "After= " .$value ."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Before= 26395593
After= 26395593
Before= 0
After= 0
Before= 2
After= 2
```

Comment: Why do you "unset" the variable? Do not unset, store the VALUE before unsetting, ...

Comment: Cast the SimpleXmlElement into a string.